# robot_upstart: Nodes using third party libraries are ignored [Python]

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, robot-upstart, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS on raspberry pi 3. I'm using two third party libraries, one for reading sensor registers from I2C ([FaBo9AXIS-MPU9250-Python](https://github.com/FaBoPlatform/FaBo9AXIS-MPU9250-Python/blob/master/FaBo9Axis_MPU9250/MPU9250.py)) and one for generating PWM signal on pins ([pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/)).
Any node `import`ing one won't start by `ros_upstart` as if it doesn't exist in the launch file (also no log file is generated). What's wrong?
Here's one of the nodes:

```
import rospy
import FaBo9Axis_MPU9250
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu


rospy.init_node('imu')

mpu9250 = FaBo9Axis_MPU9250.MPU9250()

pub = rospy.Publisher('imu/data_raw',Imu, queue_size = 1)
msg = Imu()
msg.orientation_covariance[0] = -1
msg.header.frame_id = 'imu'
rate = rospy.Rate(100)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    accel = mpu9250.readAccel()
    gyro = mpu9250.readGyro()
    
    msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

    msg.linear_acceleration.x = accel['x'] * 9.81
    msg.linear_acceleration.y = accel['y'] * 9.81
    msg.linear_acceleration.z = accel['z'] * 9.81

    msg.angular_velocity.x = (gyro['x'] - 0.9) * 0.01745329251
    msg.angular_velocity.y = (gyro['y'] - 0.5) * 0.01745329251
    msg.angular_velocity.z = gyro['z'] * 0.01745329251

    pub.publish(msg)
    rate.sleep()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279399/robot_upstart:-nodes-using-third-party-libraries-are-ignored-%5Bpython%5D/) by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-10**:
Well, it is hard to say. But as you are trying this with HW, this ist most often an issue with permissions. Check [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/robot_upstart/html/install.html#permissions) and consider setting the ports you are using to world read/writeable...

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-10**:
Thanks. What do you mean by "ports" ?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-01-10**:
Also check `PYTHONPATH` of the user that runs the service and see the directory of your python file is included.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-10**:
By port I mean the GPIO device and the I2C device. Typically (well, on Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, ...) you Need to be in the group `dialout` to get access to those devices. As the docu states, you don't have the group membership when at the point of time that `robot_upstart` starts the scripts...

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-10**:
So as I understand,`root` starts the service and the unprivileged user executes the launch file. I have to make sure the user has access to GPIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tracked down the problem to these two lines in the libraries:

```
import pigpio
```

and

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
```

Running this command solved the first problem

```
sudo chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem && sudo chmod a+x /dev/gpiomem
```

To fix the second one, I had to modify `99-com.rules` .

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
```

It was only necessary to change the mode corresponding to `i2c-dev` to  `0777` (read/write for all).

```
SUBSYSTEM=="i2c-dev", GROUP="i2c", MODE="0777"
```

Come to think of it, I could do the same for the `gpio` line  and probably fix both issues using this file.

---

Originally posted by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-11**:
That's what I'm talking about :-)
There are several ways to fix the Group permissions. Using udev is IMO the best one.

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-11**:
Thanks for `130s` and your support. It was my first time ever hearing about udev :) so it took a while to get there.